# Create mutliple dataframes by changing one column with a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am calculating heat decay from spent fuel rods using variable cooling times. How can I create multiple dataframes, by varying the cooling time column with a for loop, then write them to a file?

Using `datetime` objects, I am creating multiple columns of cooling time values by subtracting a future date from the date the fuel rod was discharged.

I then tried to use a for loop to index these columns into a new dataframe, with the intent to streamline multiple files by using newly created dataframes in a new function.

```
df = pd.read_excel('data')
df.columns = ['ID','Enr','Dis','Mtu']

# Discharge Dates
_0 = dt.datetime(2020,12,1)
_1 = dt.datetime(2021,6,1)
_2 = dt.datetime(2021,12,1)
_3 = dt.datetime(2022,6,1)

# Variable Cooling Time Columns
df['Ct_0[Years]'] = df['Dis'].apply(lambda x: (((_0 - x).days)/365))
df['Ct_1[Years]'] = df['Dis'].apply(lambda x: (((_1 - x).days)/365))
df['Ct_2[Years]'] = df['Dis'].apply(lambda x: (((_2 - x).days)/365))
df['Ct_3[Years]'] = df['Dis'].apply(lambda x: (((_3 - x).days)/365))

# Attempting to index columns into new data frame
for i in range(4):
    df = df[['ID','Mtu','Enr','Ct_%i[Years]'%i]]
    tfile = open('Inventory_FA_%s.prn'%i,'w')
    ### Apply conditions for flagging
    tfile.close()
```

I was expecting the created cooling time columns to be indexed into the newly defined dataframe `df`. Instead I received the following error;

```
KeyError: "['Ct_1[Years]'] not in index"
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: your data frame  have duplicated column named 'Ct_1[Years]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your dataframe in each iteration of your loop with the line:

```
df = df[['ID','Mtu','Enr','Ct_%i[Years]'%i]]
```

which is why you are fine on your first iteration (error doesn't say anything about `'Ct_0[Years]'` not being in the index), and then die on your second iteration. You've dropped everything but the columns you selected in your first iteration. Select your columns into a temporary df instead:

```
for i in range(4):
    df_temp = df[['ID','Mtu','Enr','Ct_%i[Years]'%i]]
    tfile = open('Inventory_FA_%s.prn'%i,'w')
    ### Apply conditions for flagging using df_temp
    tfile.close()
```

Depending on what your conditions are, there might be a better way to do this that doesn't require making a temporary view into the dataframe, but this should help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a new dataframe? is it only to reorganize/drop columns?.Engineero is right you are effectively rewriting df on each iteration.

Anyways you could try:

```
dfnew = pd.Dataframe()
dfnew = df[['ID','Mtu','Enr']]
for i in range(4):
    dftemp = df[['Ct_%i[Years]'%i]]
    dfnew.join(dftemp)
```

Comment: I was creating new dataframes to run them through an equation to calculate heat decays based on different cooling times. There was probably an easier way to do this, but the function that had the equation was already written and I didn't want to change it. Thanks for the help!